Is my circuit diagram correct?
Check title.
Task: Design a schematic diagram with 3 lamps (A, B, C), a buzzer, and a bell. Bulbs A, B, C are controlled by a three-gang switch (S3 CBA). The buzzer is controlled by a start push button, and the bell is controlled by another start push button.
Sequence to follow for loads: Bulb A, Buzzer, Bulb B, Bell,  Bulb C
Sequence to follow for controllers: P.B. Bell, S3 CBA, P.B. Buzzer.
It seems messy, how can I improve my circuit diagram?

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

This will switch on all three lamps at the same time, won't that break the desired sequence?

What I meant with "sequence" is that the loads given should be arranged from left to right in making the diagram.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Tips for schematics:

We read left to right, top to bottom as with normal European writing. Make your schematic flow in that way.
We draw positive on top, negative on bottom (as much as possible) so that current flows from top to bottom.
Avoid crossing wires if possible while maintaining logical layout.

Comments:

"Sequence to follow for loads" doesn't make any sense. It doesn't matter electrically whether the schematic is arranged A, B, C, Buzzer, Bell or any other sequence - unless there is something missing from your question.
The "three-gang switch (S3 CBA)" suggests three individual switches in the one plate or group. Electrically they are three separate switches and would be named SW1, SW2 and SW3.


simulate this circuit
Figure 2. Same circuit, rearranged to be obscure!
The question (as you have provided it) is very poorly worded and the purpose of the exercise is not clear.

Thank you so much! The diagrams were more organized. What I meant with "sequence" is that the loads and controllers given should be arranged from left to right.

Yes, it is messy

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Positive to the top.
Avoid unneccessary crossovers.
I've kept the 'sequence' as for your OP. It's of course electrically irrelevant, especially as it obfuscates the diagram. Are you supposed to be drawing some sort of 'sequencer' that switches the loads in sequence? I'm further confused by the bell and buzzer switches being described as 'start' switches.

Thank you!! As for your questions, I don't really know. These are the only details given by our instructor
